# Is z3 4.0 C# API can only targeted .net 4.0 framework?

Tags: z3

We have a large system of .net framework 3.5, but seems that z3 4.0 C# API is only meant for .net framework 4.0. Is there anyway for our system to use that API without upgrading the .net framework version currently (it is quite hard to do so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code for the .NET interface requires .NET 4.0 because it depends on some features that were first introduced in this release (e.g., System.Numerics and System.Collections.Concurrent). Upgrading to 4.0 should not be a major problem though, and it is only required for the top-level application as it should be backwards-compatible with other components that were compiled for the 3.5 framework (with few exceptions, see [MSDN .NET version compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)).

If your code does not require BigIntegers, it would be possible to work around these issues for us; I could create a "special edition" just for you. There is some effort involved with this though, and there would be no future updates, so we should only consider this if it is absolutely necessary.

We are currently looking into the possibility of releasing the source code of the .NET API, so in the future such adapdations and modifications can be done by end-users themselves. Until that is the case, I would request interested users to contact myself directly so we can discuss "special editions" on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Yes, we really need Z3 4.0 DLL for .net framework 3.5 quite urgently. Could you please kindly send the required information to get the "special editions" to jackuct1 [at] gmail.com? Appreciate for your help.